# When are routed react components mounted and unmounted?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm testing react-router-dom behavior for a project I will be working on. I've been looking at the component mounting behavior and have run into an issue I can't find an explanation for. The closest explanation I've found in their documentation is this:

"When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the component prop, you would create a new component every render. This results in the existing component unmounting and the new component mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the children prop (below)."

What I get from this is that if I provide a react component (rather than an inline function) to the route as the route component it should only mount once, then update the mounted component. In the code snippet below, <s>it looks like the Interval component is being mounted again, but never unmounting.</s> it looks like the component is re mounted every time, as if I'm passing an inline function.

Is this the expected behavior?

<s>If it is, I'm looking for different behavior, either a single mount, or an unmount when the component is no longer being rendered. Is this possible with react-router-dom?</s>

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Container, Col, Row } from 'reactstrap'

function RouteLinks() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">None</Link>
            </li>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <li>
              <Link to="/interval">interval</Link>
            </li>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">about</Link>
            </li>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function PageRouter() {
  return (
    <Container fluid={true}>
    <Router>
      <RouteLinks />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
        <Route path="/interval" component={Interval} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div>Main!</div>
  )
}

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>About!</div>
  )
}
class Interval extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('ticking')
    }, 1000)
    console.log('mounted')
  }
  componentWilUnmount() {
    console.log('unmounting')
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>Interval</p>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your `Interval` class: `componentWilUnmount`, should be `componentWillUnmount`

Comment: @Lennholm well that's embarrassing. Thank you.